# How to position text in the top of all columns in the upper row of a table [diagbox]

Tags: tables, diagbox

How can I get '1', '2', '3', '4', and 'Supply' (i.e. the entries in the first row (but in different columns)) on the same height (vertical position) as 'Destination' (i.e. at the top of the columns instead of in the middle of the columns)?
Due to using the 'diagbox' option, the vertical position of these elements is off.

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{keyval}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx,colortbl}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
  \caption[caption]{Table 1}
  \label{tab:table1}
\begin{tabular}{|l|cccc|c|}
\hline
\diagbox{\textbf{Source}}{\textbf{Destination}} & $1$ & $2$ & $3$ & $4$ & \textbf{Supply} \\
\hline
$1$ & $c_{11}$ & $c_{12}$ & $c_{13}$ & $c_{14}$ & $s_1$ \\
$2$ & $c_{21}$ & $c_{22}$ & $c_{23}$ & $c_{24}$ & $s_2$ \\
$3$ & $c_{31}$ & $c_{32}$ & $c_{33}$ & $c_{34}$ & $s_3$ \\
$4$ & $c_{41}$ & $c_{42}$ & $c_{43}$ & $c_{44}$ & $s_4$ \\
\hline
\textbf{Demand} & $d_1$ & $d_2$ & $d_3$ & $d_4$ & $T$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: please be so kind ans extend your code snippet to complete small document, which we can copy and test as it is in our computers! now wee need to gues which package you use for this table etc ...

Comment: @Zarko Done, I use relatively many packages so it was kind of difficult to select the useful ones, but I think this represents the problem well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

meanwhile when you wait on desired solution, see if the following redesign of your table is acceptable to you:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{article}
%\usepackage{pict2e}       % not needed in this mwe
%\usepackage{keyval}       % not needed in this mwe
%\usepackage{calc}         % not needed in this mwe
%\usepackage{fp}           % not needed in this mwe
%\usepackage{diagbox}      % not needed in this mwe
\usepackage{booktabs,
            multirow,       % <--- new
            tabularx}       % <--- new
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}  % <--- changed from colortbl

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h!]
\caption[short caption]{long caption}
\label{tab:table1}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{*{6}{>{$}c<{$}} }
    \toprule
\multirow{2.4}{*}{\textbf{Source}}
    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Destination}}
        & \multirow{2.4}{*}{\textbf{Supply}}    \\
    \cmidrule{2-5}
    &  1     & 2      & 3      & 4      &       \\
    \midrule
1   & c_{11} & c_{12} & c_{13} & c_{14} & s_1   \\
2   & c_{21} & c_{22} & c_{23} & c_{24} & s_2   \\
3   & c_{31} & c_{32} & c_{33} & c_{34} & s_3   \\
4   & c_{41} & c_{42} & c_{43} & c_{44} & s_4   \\
    \midrule
\textbf{Demand}
    & d_1    & d_2    & d_3    & d_4    & T     \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**edit:** or you more prefer the following solution:

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{booktabs,
            multirow}      % <--- new
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % <--- changed from colortbl

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
  \caption[caption]{Table 1}
  \label{tab:table1}
\begin{tabular}{|l|cccc|c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{
\diagbox{\textbf{Source}}{\textbf{Destination}}
                }
    & $1$ & $2$ & $3$ & $4$ & \textbf{Supply}   \\
    &     &     &     &     &                   \\
\hline
$1$ & $c_{11}$ & $c_{12}$ & $c_{13}$ & $c_{14}$ & $s_1$ \\
$2$ & $c_{21}$ & $c_{22}$ & $c_{23}$ & $c_{24}$ & $s_2$ \\
$3$ & $c_{31}$ & $c_{32}$ & $c_{33}$ & $c_{34}$ & $s_3$ \\
$4$ & $c_{41}$ & $c_{42}$ & $c_{43}$ & $c_{44}$ & $s_4$ \\
\hline
\textbf{Demand} & $d_1$ & $d_2$ & $d_3$ & $d_4$ & $T$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

it's probably not difficult to guess which solution I prefer ...

**addendum:**

according to your new question in the comment below ... if i correctly understood it, than you looking for the following:

[image]

in above table for the first column is used column type `S` provided by the package `siunitx`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,
            multirow}       % <--- new
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}  % <--- instead of colortbl
\usepackage{siunitx}        % <--- new

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h!]
\caption[short caption]{long caption}
\label{tab:table1}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=1.0,
                  table-space-text-post={*}]    % <--- new
                *{5}{>{$}c<{$}}
                }
    \toprule
{\multirow{2.4}{*}{\textbf{Source}}}
    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Destination}}
        & \multirow{2.4}{*}{\textbf{Supply}}    \\
    \cmidrule{2-5}
    &  1     & 2      & 3^*    & 4^\ast &       \\ % two cases how to write *
    \midrule
1   & c_{11} & c_{12} & c_{13} & c_{14} & s_1   \\
2   & c_{21} & c_{22} & c_{23} & c_{24} & s_2   \\
3*  & c_{31} & c_{32} & c_{33} & c_{34} & s_3   \\
4*  & c_{41} & c_{42} & c_{43} & c_{44} & s_4   \\
    \midrule
\textbf{Demand}
    & d_1    & d_2    & d_3    & d_4    & T     \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

in the case that `*` is intended to write some notes in table, than may the `threeparttable` can help you in this.

Comment: The first table is absolutely beautiful. Yeah, I think I'll go for that one, since it looks definitely better than what I first intended. Thank you.

Comment: One small question remaining though: I have to include a subscript star (*) to 3 and 4 but that results in a 1 and 2 at the position of the star (center-right aligned) instead of at the position of 3 and 4 (center-left aligned). How can I fix that?

Comment: @Anna, sorry, i not understand you. can you write as math expression, what is your problem, i.e. if instead of 3 and 4 you like to have 3_{*} and 4_{* }(3_{\ast} and 4_{\ast})? if you wrote so, where you expect position of star? as 3\ast?

Comment: I have 3^{\ast} and 4^{\ast} instead of just 3 and 4. 1 and 2 are without superscript *. If you run the code you see that 1 and 2 are then not positioned nicely, i.e. 1 and 2 are above the *'s of 3 and 4 but not right above the actual numbers as they should be (that's what I meant with center-left aligned vs center-right aligned).

Comment: i guess that you talking about positioning of numbers in the first column. they are horizontal centered but you like to have numbers to be right aligned and * should bi right of numbers. do i'm right? for this the column type should be changed. an example i will prepare asap.

Comment: Yeah. I think you're right. The centering in the first column is slightly off that's the (minor) problem (caused by the superscript asterisks to the numbers 3 and 4).

Comment: Again, thank you very much @Zarko. It looks great now.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite possible with some `\raisebox`es,  but I don't think it's so nice:

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{keyval}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx,colortbl, makecell, caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
  \caption[caption]{Table 1}
  \label{tab:table1}
\begin{tabular}{|l|*{4}{>{$}c<{$}}|>{$}c<{$}|}
\hline
\diagbox[innerwidth =40mm, height =15mm]%,innerleftsep = 12pt
{\raisebox{2.5ex}{\textbf{Source}}}{\raisebox{-0.5ex}{\textbf{Destination}}} & \raisebox{2.25ex}{$1$} & \raisebox{2.25ex}{$2$} & \raisebox{2.25ex}{$3$} & \raisebox{2.25ex}{$4$} & \raisebox{2.25ex}{\textbf{Supply}} \\
\hline
1 & c_{11} & c_{12} & c_{13} & c_{14} & s_1 \\
2 & c_{21} & c_{22} & c_{23} & c_{24} & s_2 \\
3 & c_{31} & c_{32} & c_{33} & c_{34} & s_3 \\
4 & c_{41} & c_{42} & c_{43} & c_{44} & s_4 \\
\hline
\textbf{Demand} & d_1 & d_2 & d_3 & d_4 & T\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]